SystemVerilog help, I'm stuck
Please help with this SystemVerilog code. The intended behavior is that the seven-segment displays 7 and 5 will show the current inputs, and the segment displays 0 and 1 will be the two-digit result of a single-digit BCD adder, from the module BCDadd. The idea for BCDadd is that if the sum is greater than nine (i.e. A-F on a seven-segment display), we should correct it by adding 6 and setting carryout, co, to a logic high to indicate the tens place.
The intended use of this code is to flash it to a FPGA board, like the simulator shown in this imgur. Here, the left[3:0] display input a, the right[7:4] display input b, the right[3:0] displays the result s, and the central LED displays co. If you noticed the problem, 8+8 isn't 10. I notice co is asserted but the sum is zero. I'm wondering why the condition if (sum>4'b1001) is not being met. I quickly modified to if(sum>4'b1001 | co), but this has negative results as shown in this second image.
I'm stuck, I do not know why this isn't working. The important module here is bcdadd1, but I have provided all of the modules in case my problem isn't there.

`default_nettype none
// Empty top module

module top (
    // I/O ports
    input  logic hz100, reset,
    input  logic [20:0] pb,
    output logic [7:0] left, right, ss7, ss6, ss5, ss4, ss3, ss2, ss1, ss0,
    output logic red, green, blue,

    // UART ports
    output logic [7:0] txdata,
    input  logic [7:0] rxdata,
    output logic txclk, rxclk,
    input  logic txready, rxready
);

    logic co;
    logic [3:0] s;
    bcdadd1 ba1(.a(pb[3:0]), .b(pb[7:4]), .ci(pb[19]), .co(co), .s(s), .r(red), .test({left[7:0], right[7:0]}));
    ssdec s0(.in(s), .out(ss0[6:0]), .enable(1));
    ssdec s1(.in({3'b0,co}), .out(ss1[6:0]), .enable(1));
    ssdec s5(.in(pb[7:4]), .out(ss5[6:0]), .enable(1));
    ssdec s7(.in(pb[3:0]), .out(ss7[6:0]), .enable(1));

endmodule

module fa(
  input logic a, b, ci,
  output logic s, co
);
  assign {co,s} = a + b + ci;
endmodule

module fa4(
  input logic [3:0] a, b,
  input logic ci,
  output logic [3:0] s,
  output logic co
);
  logic c0, c1, c2;
  fa f1(.a(a[0]), .b(b[0]), .ci(ci), .s(s[0]), .co(c0));
  fa f2(.a(a[1]), .b(b[1]), .ci(c0), .s(s[1]), .co(c1));
  fa f3(.a(a[2]), .b(b[2]), .ci(c1), .s(s[2]), .co(c2));
  fa f4(.a(a[3]), .b(b[3]), .ci(c2), .s(s[3]), .co(co));
endmodule

//Trouble with this module:
module bcdadd1(
  input logic [3:0] a, b,
  input logic ci,
  output logic [3:0] s,
  output logic co, r,
  output logic [15:0] test
);
  logic [3:0] sum;
  
  fa4 f1(.a(a), .b(b), .ci(ci), .s(sum), .co(co));
  
  always_comb begin
    if (sum > 4'b1001) begin
      s = sum + 4'b0110;
    end 
    else begin
      s = sum;
    end
  end
  assign test[11:8] = a;
  assign test[7:4] = b;
  assign r = co;
  assign test[3:0] = s;
endmodule

module ssdec(
  input logic [3:0] in,
  input logic enable,
  output logic [6:0] out
);
logic [15:0] sA, sB, sC, sD, sE, sF, sG;

  assign sA = 16'b1101011111101101;
  assign sB = 16'b0010011110011111;
  assign sC = 16'b0010111111111011;
  assign sD = 16'b0111100101101101;
  assign sE = 16'b1111110101000101;
  assign sF = 16'b1101111101110001;
  assign sG = 16'b1110111101111100;

  assign out[0] = sA[in] & enable;
  assign out[1] = sB[in] & enable;
  assign out[2] = sC[in] & enable;
  assign out[3] = sD[in] & enable;
  assign out[4] = sE[in] & enable;
  assign out[5] = sF[in] & enable;
  assign out[6] = sG[in] & enable;

endmodule




(While I have doubts about passing .co straight to fa4 f1, the co assignment in the else branch looks bogus.)

Would it be wiser to create a temporary c1, and assign co = c1 within the else? The only reason the co assignment is there is to prevent the compiler from complaining about an inferred latch.

I think "bcdadd1.co" should be 0/false when the sum is 9 or smaller. So yes, passing the fa4's co seems the right thing to do. (Using fa4 "as a 1st stage and "+ 4'b0110" for correction looks mixing levels.)

When I try to compile your code, I get compile errors.  If your simulator does not report errors (or at least warnings), try your code on another simulator, such as those on edapayground.
In the bcdadd1 module, the co signal has multiple drivers:

The f1 instance output
The always_comb block

You probably don't need to drive co from the always_comb block:
  always_comb begin
    if (sum > 4'b1001) begin
      s = sum + 4'b0110;
    end 
    else begin
      s = sum;
    end
  end

To debug further, make sure you look at waveforms of all the signals in the module when you run the simulation.

probably don't need to drive co from the always_comb block try 7 + 6.

This is great. However, how would I go about indicating that the sum was carried out? As currently the if-else logic is now working as intended, but I lose the ability to conditionally update co. Very unfortunate that the compiler I have been given (for school) didn't report the issue, I appreciate the recommendation for edaplayground, and will be using that in the future.

@David: Great, you are making progress towards a solution.  Answer update with more advice.

The intended use of this code is to flash it to a FPGA board, like the simulator shown in this imgur: https://imgur.com/a/LA9PiKh. Here, the left[3:0] display a, the right[7:4] display b, the right[3:0] displays s, and the central LED displays co. If you noticed the problem, 8+8 isn't 10. I notice co is asserted but the sum is zero. I'm wondering why the condition if (sum>4'b1001) is not being met. I quickly modified to if(sum>4'b1001 | co), but this has negative results as shown in this second image:  https://imgur.com/a/S0DiyPe

@David: You need to focus your question very narrowly to solve your problem.  I recommend you Accept
this answer since it identifies a major problem with your code.  Instead of repeatedly editing your question, post a new question with just the Verilog module you are having trouble with, plus the Verilog testbench code so we can run a simulation.
